# SQL Select Max of Columns Where Date is Not Null

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently am using this query to select some data: 
`SELECT DISTINCT a.code AS code, name, max(scen.Is3D) AS Is3D  FROM locations LEFT JOIN ...`. The `scen` table has columns `Is3D` and `Date`. I only want to select the max of items where the date `IS NOT NULL`. I tried `max(scen.Is3D WHERE scen.Date IS NOT NULL)`, but that didn't work. I cannot change anything after the `FROM` in my query, so I need that filtering to be done in the MAX, if possible. I am using MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN scen.date IS NOT NULL THEN scen.Is3D END) AS Is3D
```

The `CASE` expression returns `NULL` when none of the `WHEN` conditions is met, but `MAX()` ignores null values, so this will just return the max of the `Is3D` columns in the selected rows.

Comment: I changed answers because this is simpler and makes more sense for what I'm doing

Answer (score 1):

So if we can't change anything after the `FROM`, then we cannot get a perfect solution here. Since you are `SELECT`ing out the `NULL` values. One thing that we can try if we can only modify the final output is this.

`SELECT MAX(ISNULL(scen.Date,0))...`

This will replace all the `NULL`s with 0, but it would help to know exactly what you are trying to do. Why are you so convinced that the query itself cannot be modified in any way?

The other solution would be to put the whole query in another wrapper.

That would look like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
[your whole query here]
) AS inner
WHERE inner.Date IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The wrapper would definitely work but not sure it's an option.  (guess it is)

Comment: You're supposed to be checking the `Date` column for `NULL`, not `Is3D`.